# How can I hide empty columns in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using C# & asp.net

if there is no data's in the table, gridview displaying one rows (it was empty)

I want to hide the gridview empty row.

How to do this.

Answer (score 2):

try with this code

```
gridview.Visible =  (yourDataTable.Rows.Count > 0) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following properties of [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx).

**EmptyDataRowStyle**
Gets a reference to the TableItemStyle object that enables you to set the appearance of the empty data row rendered when a GridView control is bound to a data source that does not contain any records.

**EmptyDataTemplate**
Gets or sets the user-defined content for the empty data row rendered when a GridView control is bound to a data source that does not contain any records.

**EmptyDataText**
Gets or sets the text to display in the empty data row rendered when a GridView control is bound to a data source that does not contain any records.

Comment: This is what I do. It at least then lets the user know there was no results. UI is king.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
yourDataGrid.Rows[0].Visible = false;
```